# How to disable "are you sure" window for deleting system files?

Tags: windows-7

Windows keeps bugging me with this "Are you sure you want to delete thumbs.db? But it's a system file!" window. Is there a way to permanently disable this?

Comment: No it's not possible besides stopping deleting the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable that prompt, however, you can stop it from creating them. Open up a notepad document and type in the following:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer] 
"NoThumbnailCache"=dword:00000001
```

Save it as "NoThumbs.reg" and run it. Reboot your PC and it should take effect.